# I can't run an exe file completely hidden

Tags: windows, exe, hidden

I tried to run a program called MSIAfterburner with no windows
But nothing works
I tried

Quiet.exe

Nircmd.exe

I tried some python scripts and JavaScript & Powershell and VBS. And every time it was showing the window of the program
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither `quiet.exe` nor `nircmd.exe` come with windows by default. I believe this `MSIAfterburner` program you are referring to is a graphics overclocking utility, which is a **windows application**, as opposed to a **console application**.

Therefore, if you for whatever reason want to run it **without a window**, the easiest way I can think of would be to launch the program in a different session using `psexec -i 0` (run it as admin) from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec).

If you want to run it without a window **without admin privileges**, the best I can think of would be to use the winapi `ShowWindow(handle_to_the_app_main_window, SW_HIDE)`.

Comment: psexec didn't work as the picture [here](https://a.top4top.io/p_2044n1gzu1.png)

Comment: Can you please give me some details about How to use winapi ShowWindow?

Comment: Yes, psexec failed, but read the error. It says 'cannot find the file specified'. Try specifying the full path of the file.

Comment: Thank you mate. It worked but again How can I use winapi? Can I use it by coding a C# Application to run the program?